# Between clause on Array of numerical values in row for JSON type column

Tags: json, sql-server, json-value

I have a table with single column containing JSON type objects (column type `nvarchar`) and have a requirement of filtering rows.

JSON object is an array of objects containing multiple fields, Is there a way I can apply between clause on each value of array and return that row if it matches.

```
ROW_1 = [{"key": 12}, {"key": 13}, {"key": 19}]
```

For the above string if between clause has range between 15 to 22, then this row should be selected.

There are two challenges I see in above requirement, 1 is to use wild_cards to select all keys and other to apply between clause on each value.

Similar use-case, is to select a row if it matches the value for which I did something like below

```
select * 
from table 
where CAST(JSON_QUERY(column, '$'), nvarchar(max)) LIKE '%"key": 12%'
```

Let me know if this can be done using a T-SQL query.

PS. Other alternatives include loading all data using python and filter there. (but my concern is that I would  need to load complete data every time which might slowdown the filtering due to increase in number of rows in future).

Comment: Which should be between `15 to 22`? Any of the key's value or all of the key's value?

Comment: The JSON is not valid (it should be `[{"key": 12}, {"key": 13}, {"key": 19}]`).

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy Any of the key's value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an `APPLY` operator and an `OPENJSON()` call to parse the stored JSON and apply the appropriate `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES (N'[{"key": 12}, {"key": 13}, {"key": 19}]')) v (JsonData)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(v.JsonData) WITH ([key] int '$.key') j
WHERE j.[key] BETWEEN 5 AND 12
```